# Lockmodetype.Pessimistic_Read is locking rows other than locked rows

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, locking

I'm writing a JUnit test case to verify that pessimistic read on a particular row in one thread is not locking select calls for other rows in another thread.

### Please see the pseudo code below:

```
public test(){

    service a = new service(entitymanager1);
    entitymanager1.beginTxn();
    a.methodToLockRow1();//has pessimistic_read lock to select 1st row

    new Thread(){
    run(){

        service a2 = new service(entitymanager2);
        entitymanager2.beginTxn();
        a2.methodToSelectRow2();//has no lock specified. only selects 2nd row  
        entitymanager2.commit();

    }
    }.start();

    Thread.sleep(5000)
    entitymanager1.commit();
}
```

---

I expected `a2.methodToSelectRow2()` to execute without waiting for `a.methodToLockRow1()` to commit. But that is not happening.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: can you show how do you actually lock the entities?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to acquire a shared lock in the second method using again the PESSIMIST_READ. Without that the second transaction will not be able to commit().. until the first transaction finishes.

There is a great article with examples here -> [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/)

Comment: thanks for your response. PESSIMIST_READ on the second query also didn't resolve it. I think the select query in a2.methodToSelectRow2() scans entire table. so probably it's waiting for lock to release....not quite sure...

Comment: maybe you can post the queries or entire transactinal methods.. and lets see

Answer (score 0):

We resolved by placing the lock on a dummy table instead of the same table. Thank you.